# Symfony 1.4 and Jenkins?

Tags: symfony1, jenkins

Has anyone worked with Jenkins and Symfony 1.4? It uses limetest and i have no idea if it has a compatibility mode with Jenkins!

Comment: What "compatibility mode" do you need? Jenkins can run any executable or script you want and check for any patterns in it's output. So if you don't find Jenkins plugin for your particular tool, just use the generic ones.

Answer (score 6):

Symfony have two tasks for testing: test:unit and test:functional. Both of these are able to write Junit xml log files:

```
$ php symfony help test:unit
... snip ...

 The task can output a JUnit compatible XML log file with the --xml options:

 ./symfony test:unit --xml=log.xml
```

and:

```
$ php symfony help test:functional 

 The task can output a JUnit compatible XML log file with the --xml
 options:

   ./symfony test:functional --xml=log.xml
```

That said, if you are gonna manage your continuous integration of a symfony project (and more generally any PHP project) with Jenkins, you should take a look at http://jenkins-php.org/ with is the best ressource in my opinion on how to set up CI for this. This makes integrating Symfony projects test validation into Jenkins a dream.